# Is it possible to install Sitecore CMS on Mono on Linux or Mac?

Tags: .net, content-management-system, mono, installation, sitecore

I know its not supported for production use (or tech support won't answer your cases) but does anyone know if it is **technically possible to install the Sitecore .NET CMS on Mono on Linux or OS X?**

Preferably experiences with the latest Sitecore 6.5 or even Sitecore OMS would be good. It would be nice for us to have it running (for limited development purposes only) on our Linux and Mac laptops rather than Windows and IIS.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Joe.

Answer (score 3):

After running a [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) analysis - I'd say go on and try it. There are several `Not Implemented` methods, but with caveats, nothing is outright missing. However, there are over 20 P/Invoke calls - this might break Sitecore if the authors didn't expect for the not to be available in some scenarios.

Comment: Thankyou so much! will give it a go (and sorry I should maybe have known about the MoMA tool).

Comment: Please be sure to blog about this either way, if it doesn't work we can maybe put some pressure on Sitecore to get this working...

Answer (score 1):

Really old question but Sitecore is now moving towards micro services using .NET Core beginning in 8-version and continuing in the 9-version series. You can run .NET Core stuff on Linux and Mac. I.e. some parts you should be able to run on Linux already now, but not all parts yet.

- .NET Core on Linux: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x
- .NET Core on Mac: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/macos-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: Worth mentioning that Sitecore stated this in 2016 and there's been no update at all on their progress since. 3 years later Sitecore still depends on .NET Framework. Sitecore is also one complete package, so you can't just host bits and pieces of it separately.